# Vuetify SASS not compiling correctly with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I wanna make Vuetify work with Nuxt via Plugin but get the problem of :
[image]

Textform:

```
 ERROR  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VProgressLinear/VProgressLinear.sass                                                                                                                                                                                                                         friendly-errors 21:22:30

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          friendly-errors 21:22:30

undefined
   ^
      Invalid CSS after "    @content": expected "}", was "($material-light); "
```

I installed all the necessary Sass Loaders according to Vuetify and Nuxt´s Docs. I set up a Example Repository barebone to recreate the problem. https://github.com/Badgyy/vdling

Sitting on the problem for hours now but didn´t find any suitable solution online, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are using node-sass, while you should be using sass.

Also, I suggest just to use [nuxtjs/vuetify](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module) module, that will install all deps correctly and do all needed configuration

Comment: Yes I used the nuxt module for it and it worked but changing the theme settings in the nuxt config had no effect on the appearance so since i didn´t find any issue regarding that problem i tried to go the plugin route since there it worked for me in the past with theme modification

Comment: @Badgy theme modification changed in v2, check docs. It should be something like themes theme light as a key

Comment: Are you able to use nuxtjs/vuetify al-a-carte? I really only need one module from vuetify, not the whole thing.

Comment: @10000RubyPools yes, its default treeshake in vuetify production build.